# Inconsistent get_class_methods vs method_exists when using UTF8 characters in PHP code

Tags: php, oop, encoding

I have this class in a UTF-8 encoded file called **EnUTF8.Class.php**:

```
class EnUTF8 {

    public function ñññ() {

        return 'ñññ()';

    }
}
```

and in another UTF-8 encoded file:

```
require_once('EnUTF8.Class.php');
require_once('OneBuggy.Class.php');

$utf8 = new EnUTF8();
//$buggy = new OneBuggy();

echo (method_exists($utf8, 'ñññ')) ? 'ñññ() exists!' : 'ñññ() does not exist...';

echo "\n\n----------------------------------\n\n"

print_r(get_class_methods($utf8));

echo "\n----------------------------------\n\n"

echo $utf8->ñññ();
```

that produces the expected result:

```
ñññ() exists!

----------------------------------

Array
(
    [0] => ñññ
)

----------------------------------

ñññ()
```

but if...

```
require_once('EnUTF8.Class.php');
require_once('OneBuggy.Class.php');

$utf8 = new EnUTF8();
$buggy = new OneBuggy();

echo (method_exists($utf8, 'ñññ')) ? 'ñññ() exists!' : 'ñññ() does not exist...';

echo "\n\n----------------------------------\n\n"

print_r(get_class_methods($utf8));

echo "\n----------------------------------\n\n"

echo $utf8->ñññ();
```

then the weirdness appears!!!:

```
ñññ() does not exist!

----------------------------------

Array
(
[0] => ñññ
)

----------------------------------

Fatal error: Call to undefined method EnUTF8::ñññ() in /var/www/test.php on line 16
```

Well, the thing is that **OneBuggy.Class.php** is UTF-8 encoded too and shares absolutly nothing with **EnUTF8.Class.php** so...

where is the bug?

**UPDATED:**

Well, after a long debugging time I found this in **OneBuggy.Class.php** constructor:

```
setlocale (LC_ALL, "es_ES@euro", "es_ES", "esp");
```

so I did...

```
//setlocale (LC_ALL, "es_ES@euro", "es_ES", "esp");
```

and now it works but why?.

Comment: How can you get a Fatal error, and yet continue to run the following code afterwards?

Comment: That's a good question but the system admin configured our server in a really awkward way.

Comment: Ok, edited due to chelmertz comment.

Comment: I added another answer re your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your update, I think it goes into this direction:

With `setlocale()`, among other things, you set

> LC_CTYPE for character classification and conversion, for example strtoupper()

`method_exists()` is [**case insensitive**](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php#93934), so within method_exists(), some case conversion must take place. I bet the string breaks at that point. Why it would break if you explicitly set the spanish locale, but not if you don't, I don't understand, though.

Is there a specific spanish rule for uppercasing `ñ` other than making it `Ñ`? Is it possible to lowercase `ñ`?

It could also be that the spanish locale the function is trying to switch to isn't installed on your system at all, and the fallback locale is a different one than PHP uses by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with PHP 5.x, you should not develop using names in UTF-8 for your variables/classes/functions/... : in some cases, for some characters, it will work, but in a general situation, it will not.

And note this is true for identifiers, but you'll have the same problem for the content of variables, for instance -- as an example, to manipulate strings in UTF-8, you have to work with the [`mb_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) familly of functions.

This is because PHP 5.x is not really using Unicode : it's **the** big thing that's planned for PHP 6 *(which is not even in alpha stage yet)*.